# Job scheduling variation

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, greedy

I am trying to solve a variation of interval scheduling problem : Given a set of n jobs, each of which require 1 unit of processing to finish, and every job has an availability interval(a start time and end time between which it can be executed) for which it is available, find the the maximum number of jobs that can be scheduled.

The solution I tried was sorting the jobs and always picking the ones with the earliest end time of availability, while removing jobs that are not available after every iteration.

```
while jobs are not empty:
    remove jobs that are not available
    find the job with earliest end_availability_time
    execute the job
```

I am using a priority queue where I insert all the jobs in the beginning, instead of sorting.
The time complexity of this solution is `O(nlogn)` ( Every job is inserted once to the priority queue and popped once from the priority queue).

Is there an optimal way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this as an instance of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). You just have to transform the intervals in slots of one unit, and connect each job to every one-unit time interval it can be executed in.

One possible algorithm to solve this is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), or you can encode it as a [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) problem and solve it with the [Ford-Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford-Fulkerson_algorithm).

**Edit**
Thinking about it more, your solution is also optimal. Here's a sketch of the proof: let A be the optimal solution found by the greedy algorithm, and B a different optimal solution.  Consider a job j that is scheduled in B, but not in A. This means that the greedy algorithm removed j from the list of available jobs, which could happen only if it scheduled another job for every slot of time in j's availablity interval. Then, one of these jobs cannot be in B, because it would be scheduled at the same time of j. Thus means that A and B have the same number of jobs.

In other words, the greedy algorithm schedules a job at every time slot, so it must be optimal.

Comment: But they actually complicate the problem don't they? I mean the solution I have now is asymptotically better, isn't it?

Comment: @SamRadhakrishnan yours is faster, but it is not guaranteed to find the optimal solution (i.e., execute the largest number of jobs)

Comment: Are you sure? I was thinking this similar to the [activity selection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem).
Maybe I am missing something

Comment: @SamRadhakrishnan you might be right, check my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking if there's a faster solution possible.